# How to load images in a list view control with their original names and get image name by clicking onto it?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I am creating a simple image gallery where i require images that will load from a directory with their original names. i have used image list and list view control for this task .firstly i load images in image view control and by creating a thumbnail images are shown in list view control.

i am not able to get original name of images in list view control. i also want to get image's name while clicking the image.

Here is my Code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\mypics");
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
        }

        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        ListViewItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = i;
            item.Text = "Image " + i.ToString();
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the `Tag` property of `ListViewItem` with filename.

Comment: How ? @Volodymyr Melnychuk

Comment: i am getting name of the image while clicking onto it. but when i click another item, message box shows name of previous item firstly and then shows me clicked item's name. @ Volodymyr Melnychuk

Comment: well thank you @Volodymyr Melnychuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very thankful to @Volodymyr Melnychuk who guided me up to what exactly was required.

private List _filenames;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _filenames = new List();

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\mypics");
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
            _filenames.Add(file.Name);
            imageList1.Images.Add(image);
        }

        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(100, 150);
        listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
        for (int i = 0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = i;
            item.Text =_filenames[i];
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

his above code is working but later i was required list view item name by double clicking onto it. i go t some help on MSDN.

here is the code.

```
     private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
          {
           if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {

           MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Show file in ListView control:

```
dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
lvImages.DataSource = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
lvImages.DataBind();
```

In design (show file name):

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrImagePath" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:Literal>
```